# express server working, but not logging anything to vs code terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

after  I ran my application to production, creating a build file etc, the server does not respond to development testing, I tried to comment out the build code and get requests sent to

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage')
})
```

but nothing is showing in the logs for the server, the requests are all working fine and everything is running locally but just nothing shows as server recieving response to creating posts etc..

this is my server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

//Use dotenv to read .env vars into Node
require('dotenv').config();

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});


// parse body on every request //
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/postRoute'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/usersRoute'));
app.use('/api/admin', require('./routes/adminRoute'));
app.use('/api/payment', require('./routes/paymentRoute'));


// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));
    }

    // console.log(` .env mongoose string ${process.env.DB_CONN}`);

    mongoose
    .connect((process.env.MONGODB_PRODUCTION_DATABASE || process.env.MONGODB_DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE), {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    })
    .then(console.log('We have touchdown houston [DATABASE HAD CONNECTION]'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));


    // root home page

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });


    // listen to server

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log(`@.@ ==> API Server  on PORT ${PORT} now listening`);
    });
```

Comment: Your question title doesn't make sense.  How can everything be working and not responding to any requests?  Are you just saying that you don't see any logging for the server, but the server IS responding to requests just fine?

Comment: yes, the server is responding, but no logging in local development , could it be because I have a build folder?

Comment: the build folder has nothing to do with this. can you clarify exactly what you mean? when you run the server on your terminal, you aren't seeing anything? or when you console.log you don't see anything? can you be more descriptive of what the issue is

Comment: You only have one `console.log` that runs once when the server starts, the only other one is commented out, what logging are you talking about?

Comment: previously when I was in development, when I make a request , for example when I post something, I have a res.json in my backend, and I would see the response sent to the server, but now, I am not seeing any response to actions, I can see console.logs and everything is working fine, but no res is being sent to my terminal, it just says terminal is running, as the response from mongodb server, but nothing else shows for the res, I hope that makes sense, apologies for the confusion